# Where is the audio unit extension app template?

Tags: xcode, audiounit

[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/audio_engine/audio_units/creating_an_audio_unit_extension?language=objc) shows:
[image]

Yet, I open XCode (13.3.1) [image]

There is no template for this...........

Comment: FYI, tried in XCode 12.4 without luck.

Comment: Can you give a link to those docs you mention?

Comment: @soundflix https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/audio_engine/audio_units/creating_an_audio_unit_extension?language=objc

Answer (score 0):

It does also not show up in my macOS 10.15.7 / Xcode 12.4.

However, I can see **both iOS and macOS Audio Unit templates** in macOS 12 / **Xcode 14.2**:

[image]

On the other hand, the `Audio Unit Extension App template` is nothing new. I found a mention in the older [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/AudioUnit.html) which was around Xcode 7 times.

Comment: The name "Audio Unit Extension App" is the same, but the contents of the template are greatly different from the version 7 incarnation. This is the one to use.